# WSO2 DSS Error in 'SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery' when run dependent query

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have 2 connected queries. Second of them is as a Output Mapping for the first one. Parameter for the second query is taken from 1-st query's column. If value in this column is null I get a exception

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-19 10:37:30,357] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService} -  DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': null_DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR_Nested Exception:-_java.lang.NullPointerException__DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR_Source Data Service:-_Name: eLABa_Location: /Elaba.dbs_Description: N/A_Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice_Current Request Name: _getusers_code_Current Params: {code=Onishchuk}_Nested Exception:-_DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': null_DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR_Nested Exception:-_java.lang.NullPointerException__ (Sanitized) {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService}
DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': null
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NullPointerException

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: eLABa
Location: /Elaba.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: _getusers_code
Current Params: {code=Onishchuk}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': null
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NullPointerException


    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:807)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runPostQuery(SQLQuery.java:2144)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:293)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.resource.Resource.execute(Resource.java:67)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DataService.invoke(DataService.java:583)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.serialize(DSOMDataSource.java:107)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.getReader(DSOMDataSource.java:113)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getDirectReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:498)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.getXMLStreamReaderWithoutCaching(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:507)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBUtils.cloneAndReturnBuiltElement(DBUtils.java:832)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:87)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:344)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:52)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:843)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.handleRestRequest(CarbonServlet.java:303)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doGet(CarbonServlet.java:152)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': null
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:762)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.runPreQuery(SQLQuery.java:2132)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.execute(Query.java:285)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.CallQuery.executeElement(CallQuery.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElementGroup.executeElement(OutputElementGroup.java:106)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.OutputElement.execute(OutputElement.java:89)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.Query.writeResultEntry(Query.java:426)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:801)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.ExpressionQuery.processDynamicQuery(ExpressionQuery.java:327)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.createProcessedPreparedStatement(SQLQuery.java:1334)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.query.SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery(SQLQuery.java:735)
    ... 77 more
```

Comment: Cant say much without looking at your Elaba.dbs .. will you be able to share your .dbs file (content)

Comment: Sorry for no answer. I had a couple weeks of holiday. I'll prepare some example and send a dbs file